# Pandas Dataframe and Seaborn graph interaction with HTML webpage

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to render seaboard graph in HTML and make it interactive for the user. Basically, it is a regplot that by default will show all data pulled in by a SQL query.
The user can then input a certain item from a drop down list and I would like to re-run the query **and plot the same graph** but only for the selected item.

My problem is that the initial query (display all) works, but when selecting the new item, the new data is added to the old data. If I select an additional item, this is also added... not displayed by itself. See pictures attached.[image: Initial Query]

[image: Query after selecting brand]

My understanding is that the PandasDataframe is not "dropping" the data in-between queries (it only resets if I restart the program). I have tried all sorts of Pandas - memory management options, but I cannot get any of them to work.

Thank you for your help

Code:

```
@app.route('/bikeplot1')
def brandstatsinputs():
    plt.ion()
    fig = Figure()
    brandstatsx = request.args.get('Brandstats','')
    try:
        tabledata = DB.brandstats_inputs(brandstatsx)
    except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    tabledata = None

    df=pd.DataFrame(tabledata)

    sns.regplot(x="Bore", y="Stroke", data=df, scatter_kws={'alpha':0.5})

    ### Saving plot to disk in png format
    plt.savefig('Static/square_plot.png')

    ### Rendering Plot in Html
    figfile = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(figfile, format='png')
    figfile.seek(0)
    figdata_png = base64.b64encode(figfile.getvalue())
    result = str(figdata_png)[2:-1]

    return render_template('airline.html', result=result, tabledata=tabledata)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have solved this already but anyway here it goes:
I think that you have to close the figure before returning from the function. Like this:

```
...

python code

...

plt.close()
return ...
```

If that doesn't work, try `plt.close(fig)`

**Note:** This has not been tested